# Finding dominants in sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem with fragment of code. I want to find dominant among already sorted array. The thing is when there are two or more dominants in array, it only prints one. I mean situation like this:
Numbers: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5 <- so the dominants should be 1, 2 and 3. I tried many times to fix it but i guess i blocked myself up. Could anyone give me some clue?

```
n- number of integers, initiated by user
int t[n];

...generating random numbers, sorting...

int actuall, max, dominant, occurency;  

 max = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
 {
   actuall= t[i]; 
   occurency = 0;

for(int j = 0; j<n; j++) 
{
if(t[j] == actuall) occurency++;
}
if(occurency > max)
{
  max = occurency; 
 dominant = actuall;      
  }           
}

 if(max == 1){
 cout<<"\nThere is no dominant";
 }

 if(max > 1) { 
 cout << endl <<"Dominant: " << dominant <<", occurency: " << max << endl;
 }
```

Comment: One simple way, though inefficient, would be to loop over the entire array again and print all elements whose frequency is equal to `occurency`

Comment: You can unite sorting and finding your dominants using "counting sort". Since you deal with integers, a simple map<int,int> can store your values as key, and the count of that values as value. If you track current dominant, then you'll be able to output all of them in single pass over map<>. Worst case scenario is if you have many different values, then you probably shouldn't use this method.

Comment: If you fixed your code identation, you'd have already noticed that the main loop ends after the `if (occurency > max)` test block.  The print occurs outside of the loop, and can only print the last found dominant.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to do it, but almost all of them requires more than one pass over the data.

A simple method to do it, that also minimizes the amount of data needed to check for each pass, is to use e.g. a [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Use the values in the container as key, and the count of each value as the data.

Then you need one pass over the full container to populate the map, and two passes over the map (one to find the max count and one to find all entries equal to the max count).

Yes you need three passes to find all "dominants", but with your example the second and third pass only loops over five elements each instead of all eleven of the original container.

The above method also works if the original container is not sorted.